# Difference between view with class and tag in Android

Tags: android

Is there any difference between

```
<View class="android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar">
```

And

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Is there any difference?

I notice that using `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` the preview screen shows warnings.

Comment: As far as I know `<view class="...">` (notice small "v") is used when custom view is not a subclass of `View`. Don't know about any differences between what you mention.